# How to make DXF files interactive, programatically?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, dxf

I am having various DXF files. I want to develop a web application that will render a DXF file. *Also whenever user clicks a inside a room from UI, we need to perform certain tasks in a room.*

To solve that, There are some DXF parsers available online in Node JS, but parser gives list of lines, arcs, layers etc.

***The parser does not give what are different rooms and where they are residing.*** Because of that i am not able to detect on which room user has clicked and not able to make DXF as interactive.

Note: Rendering a DXF file is achieved through some online JS libs, but again Rendering library just renders a file and it does NOT know how many rooms or where they are?

In case any one has idea, please suggest.

Technology used: HTML, nodeJS, lib of JS to render and parse DXF

Comment: I have same problem, I need click event on click on hosing project master plan. When user clicks on the DXF file element I want that element information. Do let me know if you had solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue .Do let me know if you found any solution for it.Thanks in advance

Comment: Till date (July 2020) I don't have a solution on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DXF files don't support the idea of a "room" or anything like that.  The contents of the file are literally just lines and text and those lines could be anything: walls, plumbing, electrical, etc.

Your best bet would be to manually look at the DXF files and *you* decide what defines a room.  I.e., Room 123 is bounded by the points (0,0), (50,0), (0, 50), and (50, 50).